# Wordpress custom login form using Ajax

Tags: php, login, security

**Description:**
I would like to create a custom login form: username, password and remember field. This is the code I have:

**Problem:** `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 503 ()`

**What I've tried:**
**PHP:**

```
function normal_login() {
    if( !isset( $_POST ) ) {
        return ;
    }

    $username =  $_POST[ 'username' ];
    $password =  $_POST[ 'pass' ];
    $remember_me = 'on' == $_POST[ 'remember_me' ] ? true : false;

    $credentials = array(
        'user_login'    => $username,
        'user_password' => $password,
        'remember'      => $remember_me
    );

    $user = wp_signon( $credentials, false );

    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    }
    else {
        if ( !$remember_me ) {
            wp_setcookie( $username, $password, false, '', '', $remember_me );
        }
        wp_redirect( '/' );
    }
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_normal_login','normal_login' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_normal_login','normal_login' );
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $( '#login-form button[type="submit"]' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $( '#form-field-email-login' ).val();
        var pass = $( '#form-field-password' ).val();
        var remember_me = $( '#form-field-remember_me' ).is( ':checked' );
        $.ajax( {
            url: MY_AJAX_OBJ.MY_AJAX_URL,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'action': 'normal_login',
                'username': username,
                'pass': pass,
                'remember_me': remember_me,
            },
            success: function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
            },
            error: function( textStatus ) {
                console.log( textStatus );
            }
        } );
    } );

} );
```

1. What am I doing wrong? no errors in error_log.
2. Is this way secure? if not, what can I do to make it secure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues I can see but no guarantee it'll entirely fix the problem(s) - 
 can you ensure `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` are defined as `true` in your `wp-config.php` - any errors during runtime should then appear in `wp-content/debug.log`.

1. You have `! isset( $_POST )` as a conditional to check the request, but this will *always* be `false` because the `$_POST` superglobal is always set - it's just empty unless there is POST'ed data. Instead, use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST'`
2. I can't see any need for the `wp_setcookie` call. The function is deprecated and is just a wrapper for `wp_set_auth_cookie`, which is called & handled by `wp_signon` anyway.
3. If you send a redirect server-side (i.e. via PHP), the AJAX client (your browser) will silently follow the redirect and then return the response of said redirect for your callback (in your case, the homepage HTML). You would be better to send back JSON & instruct your JavaScript to do the redirect client-side (e.g. `window.location = responseData.redirectUrl`)

Comment: I see, i'll try. Thanks for your recommendations. What about security? does `wp_signon` take care of that or do I need to escape the `$_POST` fields?

Comment: Nevermind the `$_POST` fields question, it would be better if I check myself, that way I learn what the function does in its core.
Any security suggestions though?

Comment: I understand what you mean at section 3 and that's why it didn't work for me. Thanks for all your suggestions and explanation!